# Error While Intergrating Firebase Authentication in my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

I am trying to integrate the `firebase auth` with `google` in my application using Cocoa Pods. I've already installed everything which is required for the integration.But still I am facing this three errors.
I have attacehed a image here for better understanding.

[image: ERROR image]

Kindly help me if anyone have idea or faced this issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Either you have duplicate files in your project. Same files twice.
2. You have not set Target Membership in your project.

> By checking the Target Membership of your library. Select the library
>   and files relevant to your app target from the Navigator. Check on the
>   Utilities section that those files are marked as required for your app
>   target.

Thanks

Happy Coding.